# Logic Error in User Comment Function with Appwrite - React

Tags: reactjs, database, function, nosql, appwrite

I am currently facing challenges in generating unique IDs for the Comment collection using Appwrite in my React project. I have three collections in Appwrite, namely Users, Post, and Comment. In the Comment collection, I am aiming to create a unique ID that includes both the post ID and the user ID.

I have tried various approaches. However, the outcome is that only the post ID and user ID are sent successfully to the User and Post collections, while a unique ID for the Comment collection is not being created.

What I want is for all databases to be successfully sent to Appwrite, specifically the comment collection with a unique ID. Inside this collection, I would like to include the post ID, user ID, and comment text.

api.ts

```
// CREATE COMMENT
export async function createComment(postId: string, userId: string, textContent: string) {
  try {
    console.log("Creating comment with values:", { postId, userId, textContent, newComment: true });
    const newComment = await databases.createDocument(
      appwriteConfig.databaseId,
      appwriteConfig.commentCollectionId,
      ID.unique(),
      {
        post: postId,
        user: userId,
        textContent: textContent,
      }
    );

    if (!newComment) throw Error;
    return newComment;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

queries.ts

```
export const useCreateComment = () => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  return useMutation({
    mutationFn: ({post, user, textContent}: {post: string; user: string; textContent: string;}) => {
      console.log("Running mutation with values:", { post, user, textContent });
      return createComment(post, user, textContent);
    },
    onSuccess: () => {
      console.log("Mutation succeeded with result:", queryClient);
      queryClient.invalidateQueries({
        queryKey: [QUERY_KEYS.GET_POST_BY_ID],
      });
      queryClient.invalidateQueries({
        queryKey: [QUERY_KEYS.GET_RECENT_POSTS],
      });
      queryClient.invalidateQueries({
        queryKey: [QUERY_KEYS.GET_POSTS],
      });
      queryClient.invalidateQueries({
        queryKey: [QUERY_KEYS.GET_CURRENT_USER],
      });
    },
  });
};
```

Commentpage.tsx

```
import { Models } from "appwrite";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

import { checkIsLiked } from "@/lib/utils";
import {
  useLikePost,
  useSavePost,
  useDeleteSavedPost,
  useGetCurrentUser,
  useCreateComment,
} from "@/lib/react-query/queries";
import { useUserContext } from "@/context/AuthContext";

type PostStatsProps = {
  post: Models.Document;
  userId: string;
};

const PostDetailStats = ({ post, userId }: PostStatsProps) => {
  const { user } = useUserContext();
  const commentList = post.comment.map((comment: Models.Document) => comment.$id);

  const [userCommented ] = useState(commentList);
  const { mutate: createComment } = useCreateComment();
  const [ textContent, setCommentText ] = useState("");

  const { data: currentUser } = useGetCurrentUser();


  const handleCommentPost = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  
    if (textContent.trim() === "") {
      return;
    };
    console.log("Calling createComment with values:", { post: post.$id, user: userId, textContent: textContent });
    await createComment({ 
      post: post.$id, 
      user: userId,
      textContent: textContent });
      
    setCommentText("");
  };

  return (
    <div
      className={`flex flex-col ${containerStyles}`}>
      <div>
        <form
          onSubmit={handleCommentPost}
          className="flex flex-row justify-between inputcomment text-dark-1 gap-3 w-full max-w-5xl">
          <input
            type="text"
            className="labelcomment"
            placeholder="Add Comment..."
            value={textContent}
            onChange={(e) => setCommentText(e.target.value)}>
          </input>
          <button
              type="submit"
              className="sendcomment">
              <img
              width={19}
              height={19} 
              src="/assets/icons/sendcomment.svg" alt="Send" />
            </button>
        </form> 
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Commentpage;
```

Comment: You said "while a unique ID for the Comment collection is not being created". What's being generated, then?